# What are the functions of the first and last IP address of every subnet?

Tags: ip, range, ip-address, subnet

I am new to IPs and subnets. I can calculate it and know the basics. Unfortunately, I couldn't find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

IPs ending on 0 designate the network address. Commonly, this address defines the route which traffic will be sent to.

Imagine that you have two routers connected by serial, so you have two subnets with 2 different private IPs: 10.0.0.0/8 and 11.0.0.0/8. /8 defines the address length in bits (Class A IP). First router will route traffic to 10.0.0.0 and second router will route traffic to 11.0.0.0.

IPs ending on 255 designate the broadcast address, a special address used to deliver packets to all hosts in the network.

For example, in case of ARP is very useful to locate/query other device's MAC by sending to the broadcast address a packet where you ask who has the MAC of a specefied IP. All the devices will capture your ARP request and if any of them has the specified IP, then you'll get a response with the MAC, but notice that you can be tricked since MAC can be impersonated (ARP Spoofing).

Regards.

Comment: Well, the first and last IP address in a subnet does not necessarily start with 0 and end with 255. e.g. the subnet 192.168.0.64/26 has a network address of 192.168.0.64 and a broadcast address of 192.168.0.127